# When I imported new contacts, some contacts got error "record", what is that?

Tags: import, error

When I imported contacts using a CSV some rows were not imported even though their formatting was fine and matched all the other rows. When I downloaded the errors, the error was called "record". Anyone know what that means? 
I've now tried repeatedly re-entering the same six rows that were considered "record" errors and even though the data seems fine CiviCRM still won't import the contacts. Let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks,

Evann

Answer (score 2):

It's quite late now for the original poster but for those who are trying to solve this problem - it is likely that you simply need to enlarge the Excel row to show the full error. For example, it may actually be 'Record duplicates multiple contacts' which would explain why uploading is not working as expected.